# Prove that A $\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(x) & -\sin(x) & 0 \\ \sin(x) & \cos(x) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \epsilon \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, similar-matrices

Show that every orthogonal matrix A $\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ is similar to a matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} cos(x) & -sin(x) & 0 \\\\ sin(x) & cos(x) & 0 \\\\ 0 & 0 & y\end{bmatrix}$$ where $y$ equals either -1 or 1.

We can show that the eigenvalues of the matrix for some angle $x$ is $e^{ix}, e^{-ix}$ and $y$. The corresponding eigenvectors are:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
i \\\\
1 \\\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-i \\\\
1 \\\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\\\
0 \\\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we rewrite the eigenvectors so that $X_1 = U_1+iU_2, X_2 = U_1-iU_2$ and $X_3 = U_3$. Where $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are the eigenvectors. Now we can show that:

$$AU_1=cos(x)U_1 -sin(x)U_2$$
and
$$AU_2 = sin(x)U_1 + cos(x)U_2.$$

I have used the hints give in the textbook that I use, but I don't understand the last step and how this shows that the matrices are similar.

Comment: Has your textbook discussed the spectral theorem for normal matrices yet? If so, then you can use the fact that every orthogonal matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: For a direct proof, you could 1: note that $A$ must have at least one real eigenvalue (equal to $1$ or $-1$), and 2: note/show that the orthogonal complement of the span of an eigenvector associated with this eigenvalue forms a 2-dimensional invariant subspace of $A$.

Comment: To elaborate on Ben's answer slightly, note that the restriction of $A$ to this invariant subspace is still orthogonal, so this restriction must live in $O(2)$. You can argue based on the determinant of $A$ and the restriction that the restriction must in fact live in $SO(2)$. You can then do an elementary calculation (i.e. just algebra and trig identities) to prove that any element of $SO(2)$ is a rotation by some angle $\theta$.

Comment: Similarity then follows. The matrix you conjugate by to obtain the rotation + identity/flip block form is just the change of basis matrix where your new basis is the basis $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ where $u_3$ is the $\pm 1$ eigenvector, and $u_1, u_2$ are as in your answer. Similarity just means conjugating by a change of basis matrix.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins The restriction does not need to be in $SO(2)$ as the eigenvalue $\pm 1$ can be multiple. I would rather consider the orthogonal complement of the eigenspace corresponding to this real eigenvalue that we start with. If the eigenvalue is single then indeed on the complement we get a matrix with determinant $1.$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the matrix is similar to $-I$, then (using OP's notation) $y = -1$ and $x = \pi$. If the matrix is $I$, then $y = 1$ and $x = 0$. If the matrix is diag(1, 1, -1), then $y = -1$ and $x = 0$. If the matrix is diag (-1, -1, 1), then $y = 1$ and $x = \pi$. In each case the restriction is an element of $SO(2)$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins If $1$ is an eigenvalue and we consider the subspace orthogonal to only one of the eigenvectors, then the determinant of the matrix restricted to that subspace does not need to be equal $1,$ unless $1$ is a single eigenvalue. The final conclusion is fine, but the reasoning should be split into cases whether the real eigenvalue that we start with is single or multiple. If it is multiple than the reasoning is even easier, as we can have $-I$ or the matrix with eigenvalues $(\pm 1,\pm 1,\mp 1).$

Comment: Yes, after several attempts to defend my argument you're right. It seemed clear in my head when I wrote it up, but some case analysis is necessary. You either have to do a sub argument where you argue that we can pick a right-handed basis without WLOG or do some case analysis (six of one, half a dozen of the other).